# Batch to exe - invisible window

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe

I turned a batch file into an exe file using this program: http://www.f2ko.de/en/b2e.php

[image]

If I select invisible, how can I tell the program is running at all? I don't see anything even in task manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out literally seconds later. Apparently the "Details" tab in task manager shows hidden windows that processes tab doesn't.